# How to fix SignalR System.InvalidOperationException InvokeAsync only works with Single Clients

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a strongly typed Hub

```
public class GameHub : Hub<IGameHubClient>
{
//...
}

public interface IGameHubClient
{
    Task<string> Send(string message);
}
```

I use the HubContext to send like this:

```
await Clients.Others.Send("test");
```

But I get an exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: InvokeAsync only works with Single clients.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.TypedClientBuilder.IGameHubClientImpl.Send(string)
```

I have tried using a HubContext in a controller

```
private readonly IHubContext<GameHub, IGameHubClient> _hub;
//...
await _hub.Clients.All.Send("test 2");
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution in this case was to avoid return types on the client interface

```
public interface IGameHubClient
{
    Task Send(string message); //note: there is no <string> on Task
}
```

Comment: Were you trying to get a string back from the client?